# error in sqoop connecting with mysql

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I have downloaded the connector and saved the jar file under the `sqoop/lib` folder, even then I'm facing this issue.

> at@ubuntu:~$ sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost"
>   --username root --password root Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail. Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of
>   your HCatalog installation. 14/01/08 16:20:45 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool:
>   Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using
>   -P instead. 14/01/08 16:20:45 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset. 14/01/08 16:20:45 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop:
>   Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
>   load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:772)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)

Answer (score 0):

The Reason For this error is sqoop is not able to connect to specified mysql driver

Try to Place mysql jars in the below libs

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/sqoop/lib/ 
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-1.5.0-1../lib/sqoop/lib/ 
/var/lib/sqoop/

and then Restart the cluster once and run the sqoop command, then it will works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download mysql connector and place in "locationOfSqoop/sqoop/lib"
 instead of placing connector folder (mysql-connector-java-5.1.41) ,place (mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar) only jar file

"locationOfSqoop/sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"

Answer (score 0):

First download mysql driver, you can download it from

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

then place the driver in the following location where  sqoop runs (ie) in the node where sqoop runs

```
/var/lib/sqoop
```

if you didn't find the dir make one and then

place

```
mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar
```

in

```
/var/lib/sqoop
```

than restart and complete the sqoop task

Answer (score 0):

In Sqoop-1.7 mysql-connector is not present. So download the jar and copy to sqoop lib.

- Download MySql connector from following link:
  wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.tar.gz
- Extract mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.tar.gz
- Copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar to $SQOOP_HOME/lib directory
- [ If you are using Sqoop with hadoop ]: Copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar to lib directory which is present in hdfs along with other jars present in the $SQOOP_HOME/lib/